# Xamarin Forms: How to parse an .epub file?

Tags: xamarin.forms, epub

I am using [EpubReader.Cross](https://github.com/g0rdan/EpubReader.Cross) NuGet Package for reading epub files. For this, I have added a sample .epub book file to my main project and set the Build Action to EmbedResource. As per the document I try to parse the title, author, and coverImage details like below. But details are not correct, please have a look at the below code.

**My Code**

```
string fileName = "content.epub";
var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{fileName}");
EpubBook epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream);
// Book's title
string title = epubBook.Title;
Debug.WriteLine("title:>>"+title);
// Book's authors (comma separated list)
string author = epubBook.Author;
Debug.WriteLine("author:>>" + author);
// Book's authors (list of authors names)
List<string> authors = epubBook.AuthorList;
Debug.WriteLine("authors:>>" + authors.Count);
// Book's cover image (null if there is no cover)
byte[] coverImage = epubBook.CoverImage;
Debug.WriteLine("coverImage:>>" + coverImage);
```

**Output**

```
[0:] title:>>be023aa39d417e1493850a0b9de6220c
[0:] author:>>Unknown
[0:] authors:>>1
[0:] coverImage:>>
```

I think the issue is with reading the .epub file added on the project. My .epub file generated by converting a .opf file, is that cause the issue?

Comment: Did you try to read another EPUB file ?

Comment: Have you tested your converted file with an epub tool?  Have you tried to use more than one epub to test your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case , the issue wasn't caused by your code or the plugin  .  An EPUB file is a digital ebook saved in the EPUB format, an open XML-based format for digital books and publications.

Some ePUB file doesn't contain the complete information when been created . You could firstly check it in your computer

In Windows , it can been opened by **Adobe Digital Editions** or **Microsoft Edge** .

In MacOS , it can been opened by **Apple Pages** or **Apple Books** .

Comment: I have downloaded one another file from google and it is working fine. One simple question, how can I get the table of content data here?

Comment: What means of `table of content data ` ?

Comment: For books, there is an initial page that shows all the chapter's titles and other main titles. It is called table of content(TOC), see an example here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WABRLREsDOyFSwNlC7-IJk5lO4v56XNN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For some epub books downloaded from google shows the following error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XpeDJ3iWkPwpmnZIO18jd9v4a7FD2NVp/view?usp=sharing